# how to prnt json data printed from get_file_contents php function

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, echo

I printed this json from a get_file_contents output.

```
{"status":"INVALID_CREDENTIALS"}
```

Now I want to echo the content of "status" and I used

```
echo $status
```

but not working. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use json_decode to convert to php object:

```
 $json = '{"status":"INVALID_CREDENTIALS"}';
 $obj = json_decode($json);
```

Then:

```
 echo $obj->status;
```